# JavaScript in Firefox calculates wrong values on pages served by Java App Server

Tags: javascript, java, tomcat, firefox

Here's the case. I've got simple html page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Sample</title>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(screen.width);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Code is in file sample.html
When file is opened under Firefox v41.0 it shows only JS popup with value 1366 (that's my screen width).
When I put this file into running Tomcat 7.0.61 working directory and try to access it using address for eg. localhost:8080/appCtx/sample.html, the JS prompt have value 1252. A little bit too small.
The same page opened under Chrome or even IE8 gives proper value.
I've tried using

```
window.innerWidth
document.body.parentNode.width
$(window).width()
```

All with the same result.
I've tried using onLoad or setTimeout(2 sec) - same result.
I've even put this file into working dir under JBoss 6.4 (project i'm workign on in my job) - same result.
All plugins in FF are disabled.
So my question is: why JS in FF can't calculate proper window width and height when page is served by application server (servlet container)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably zoomed in that page and Firefox remembered it. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to reset zoom level (or use the menu) and try again.

Comment: We've got the winner! :) I have totally forgot that FF remembers zoom settings for individual pages. Argh..